# Повторение в строке

Tags: python

Пишу фильтр от матов в одном боте и столкнулся с проблемой, что если человек написал слово с повторением буквы, к примеру, `привеееееет` и т. д., то мой фильтр не справляется, как можно убрать повторение букв?

Comment: Приведите пример кода вашего фильтра, [добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1307271/edit) его в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
word = 'привеееееет'
word_fixed = ''.join(cur if cur != prev else '' for cur,prev in zip(word,word[1:]+' '))
print(word_fixed)
```

Вывод:

```
привет
```

Хотя тема сложная. Потом они будут регистр букв менять, потом отдельные буквы на звёздочки/проценты какие-нибудь менять, потом грамматические ошибки станут специально делать...

Comment: CrazyElf, благодарю, на счет отдельных букв которые будут заменены на другие символы не столь страшно, фильтр будет снисходителен к этому, а для тех кто будет абузить эту систему, модераторы дадут бан